# Adding public is_rsa.pub to known_hosts automatically - how to?

Tags: ssh

How to automatically add server to known_hosts ? (and not use md5 fingerprint, as I mean secure way, please not send "auto yes/accept" solutions. I want to bring required credentials from server to machine)

I'd like to update automatically my ssh `known_hosts` file to accept new server.

I assume, that I need to add server's  public key (`id_rsa.pub` obtained through secure channel), but what I see is that format is different (I've tried adding like this `awk '{print "server "$1" "$2}' id_rsa.pub > .ssh/known_hosts` with verification failed. Please note that I don't want to use md5 fingerprint due to flaws in md5). If something else than `id_rsa.pub` would be useful I can run commands on server and obtain results though trusted channel. (Please note that it is not network channel (think of physically bringing pendrive from place to another), so `ssh-keyscan` does not solve the problem, what's more id_rsa.pub is key of dropbear server that is not running at server, so only files with keys are available, not server)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name `id_rsa.pub` looks like a user's public key. This has nothing to do with `known_hosts` — `known_hosts` stores host keys. Host keys, as the name indicate, authenticate a host (i.e. a computer), whereas user keys authenticate a user. Host public keys of OpenSSH are typically located in `/etc` or `/etc/ssh` and called something like `ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`.

Dropbear has a single file containing the private key. To extract the public key (in a format that is compatible between Dropbear and OpenSSH), run

```
dropbearkey -f /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key -y | sed -n 2p >host_key.pub
```

I don't think OpenSSH comes with a command to update the `known_hosts` file. It's easy enough to do manually:

```
echo "$server_name,$server_ip_address $(cat server_ssh_host_rsa_key.pub)" >>~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

If you want to hash host names (so that someone who reads your `known_hosts` file cannot know the names of these servers — it's a very minor privacy gain), run `ssh-keygen -H` afterwards.