# Add a remote server to known_hosts automatically without ssh-keyscan

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I have a BusyBox environment without ssh-keyscan and I need to add a host to the known_host file, so that scp doesn't ask if I can trust the host.

I read [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128284/adding-public-is-rsa-pub-to-known-hosts-automatically-how-to) and it looks like it could be helpful but I think I'm missing some implications here. I don't have a real knowledge about those key-thingy-things.

Comment: How will you obtain the keys if not via a keyscan? Do you know them already?

Comment: @Fiximan Yes I have access to the remote server. But I don't know anything else about ssh host and user keys.

Comment: the only way you can do that is inverting your method ... then remote host write to your local host  inside known-hosts or exchanging temporary file with another methode  (filesharing/ftp etc....)

Comment: Well, the files you are looking for are usually in `/etc/ssh/` then and called e.g. `ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`. Note the `host` and `.pub`-part

Comment: So I have a pub key, but what do I have to do with it? copy on the local machine into `~/.ssh` ?

Comment: 1) have you tried **-o batchmode=yes** as `scp` option ? 2) can't you ssh-keyscan from another linux box ?

Comment: @Archemar wow sometimes I can't even... thank you, will try this

Comment: Entries in the `known_hosts` would be "hostname key-type KEY" (in one line), e.g. you add the hostname manually and then use `cut -d' ' -f1,2 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`. Alternatively, `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host` will auto-add it without questioning.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that from BusyBox, the host you want to add is `1.2.3.4`.

On the host, run:

```
echo -n "1.2.3.4 " >> /tmp/known_hosts && cut -d' ' -f1,2 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub >> /tmp/known_hosts
```

Now take that file `/tmp/known_hosts` and move it over to the BusyBox at the location `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.  Now you should be able to ssh `hostusername@1.2.3.4` from the BusyBox without the warning or problem.

Note that you can have multiple entries with a different ip/name and the same key. This would allow you to handle the situation where the host is moving ip addresses or you would like to interchangeably use some dns name as well as the ip to connect.

(This answer was strongly influenced by the comment by @felixjn)